# E-commerce merchant-hosted transactions

Tags: e-commerce, pci-dss

I am developing an e-commerce website, I want payment process to be done from my site. meaning user will enter credit card details in a payment page of my site.

In short users should not be redirected to payment gateway for payment processing.

I am using MasterCard MIGS

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start you'll need to use SSL when taking the customer's card details.

You'll also need to be [PCI](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/P/PCI_DSS.html) compliant, e.g.:

**Build and Maintain a Secure Network**

- Install and maintain a firewall
  configuration to protect cardholder
  data
- Do not use vendor-supplied defaults
  for system passwords and other
  security parameters

**Protect Cardholder Data**

- Protect stored cardholder data
- Encrypt transmission of cardholder
  data across open, public networks

**Maintain a Vulnerability Management Program**

- Use and regularly update anti-virus
  software
- Develop and maintain secure systems
  and applications

**Implement Strong Access Control Measures**

- Restrict access to cardholder data by
  business need-to-know
- Assign a unique ID to each person
  with computer access
- Restrict physical access to
  cardholder data

**Regularly Monitor and Test Networks**

- Track and monitor all access to
  network resources and cardholder data
- Regularly test security systems and
  processes

**Maintain an Information Security Policy**

- Maintain a policy that addresses
  information security

Ultimately, you will want to avoid storing any card details without a serious compliance headache.

Using MasterCard MIGS should mean you don't need to store any card details - just send them under SSL.